# Java Comparison of If/While Loop

Tags: java, loops, control-flow

Working on a leetcode problem described as: "Given a binary array nums and an integer k, return the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the array if you can flip at most k 0's."

I am using a sliding window approach and had produced the below code:

```
class Solution {
    public int longestOnes(int[] nums, int k) {
        int current = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int ans = 0;
           
        for (int right = 0; right < nums.length; right++){
            if (nums[right] == 0){
                current++;
            }         
            
            while (current > k){
                if (nums[left] == 0){
                    current--;
                }
                left++;
            }

            ans = right - left + 1;    
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

This produces a logical error in the ouptut where the value returned is off by 1 in either direction depending on the test. I replaced the `while` loop with in `if` statement shown in the code below which fixed the error. Why is this the case?

```
class Solution {
    public int longestOnes(int[] nums, int k) {
        int current = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int ans = 0;
           
        for (int right = 0; right < nums.length; right++){
            if (nums[right] == 0){
                current++;
            }         
            
            if (current > k){
                if (nums[left] == 0){
                    current--;
                }
                left++;
            }
            ans = right - left + 1;    
        }
            
        return ans;
    }
}
```

I expected the `while` loop to run once and be equivalent as the block should evaluate the condition on each iteration and then act if the condition is true. What is happening here?

Comment: If `current` is 2, the while body will be executed twice. If it is three, it will be executed three times. With an `if` it is guaranteed to be only executed at most once. Not sure I get what your question is – a loop loops until the condition becomes false.

Comment: Please provide a runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: And why not just put a breakpoint in your while loop and *find out* why it's running more than once?

Comment: if `nums[left]` isn't `0`, the `while` operates differently. You say the second snippet 'passes', but it's not correct. Example input: 01111111000000000000000110. You always overwrite the answer, some sort of `ans = Math.max()` or similar needs to be involved somewhere.

Comment: Thanks all good spot that the conditional logic when current overtakes k is dependent on the first number in the window being a 0, @rzwitserloot please could you elaborate on what you mean with the use of `ans = Math.max()`?

Comment: Looks like you figured it out :)

Comment: Thank you kindly, it always looks so obvious when you find the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@SiggyWeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19086268)'s question post:

> Solution found via feedback from the comments
>
> ```
> class Solution {
>     public int longestOnes(int[] nums, int k) {
>         int current = 0;
>         int left = 0;
>         int ans = 0;
>            
>         for (int right = 0; right < nums.length; right++){
>             if (nums[right] == 0){
>                 current++;
>             }         
>             
>             while (current > k){
>                 if (nums[left] == 0){
>                     current--;
>                 }
>                 left++;
>             }
>             ans = Math.max(ans,right - left + 1);    
>         }
>         return ans;
>     }
> }
> ```